# Replace Input Value by click on AJAX search value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I been able to return result value from php sql but by click on result value I cannot set the input value, how to do that, Thank you.

script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input').on("keyup input", function(){
            var input = $(this).val();
            var result = $(this).parent().parent().next(".result");
            if(input.length){
                $.get("backend-search.php", {term: input}).done(function(data){
                    result.html(data);
                });
            } else{
                result.empty();
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
            $(this).prev().children().children('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
            result.empty();
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
 <div>

        <div>
            <ol style="list-style: none;">
                <li>
                    <input id='input' type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." />
                </li>
            </ol>

            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: You are declaring result inside your keyup event and trying to use it inside your click event. "result is not defined"

Comment: Is `$(this).prev().children().children('input[type="text"]')` trying to target the initial `<input>`?  If so, why not just use `$('#input')`?  Or better yet, `let $input = $('#input');` once, outside any handlers, and then use `$input` everywhere you need to reference it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I won't do that because later on i will create multiple same input and same result div , i just want to target the input that from the same div

Comment: OK, how about`$(this).parent().parent().find('input')`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes it works !! Thank you ! but i wonder why my code doesn't work because it seems it will logically works right ? have any ideas why ?

Comment: @JsonPrime I've added an answer with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your set of results looks something like this:

```
<div class='result'>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Then work through what this selector is doing if you click, say, the 2nd `<p>`:

```
$(this).prev().children().children('input[type="text"]')
```

- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) will target the "*immediately preceding sibling*".  For our example case that would select the first `<p>`;
- Next, [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) searches *down* the DOM tree for children of that `<p>`.  You haven't shown us what that HTML looks like but most likely it is plain text, with no children.  Even if it has some (eg `<span>`), it isn't going to help us get back to the `<input>`, this is the wrong direction.

You really need to search back *up* the DOM first, until we get to something that includes the input, and then back down.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input')
```

- The first [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) will select the `<div class='result'>`;
- The 2nd will target the parent `<div>` which includes both your input and your results;
- The [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will search *down* from that node looking for an input;

You can simplify this, and make it a little bit safer from future HTML changes, by adding a class to the element which contains both input and results.  In a comment you mention you plan to have multiple sets of them, so maybe each "set" could be called a "search":

```
<div class='search'>
    <ol> ... <input> ... </ol>
    <div class='result'> ... </div>
</div>

<div class='search'>
    <ol> ... <input> ... </ol>
    <div class='result'> ... </div>
</div>
```

Now it is much easier to target the right elements using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('.search').find('input')
```

Comment: I miss the part wheres ```prev()``` on multiples ```<p>``` will be the problem , this is a very clear explanation , Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#input").on("keyup input", function () {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var result = $(this).parent().parent().next(".result");
    if (input.length) {
      $.get("backend-search.php", {
        term: input,
      }).done(function (data) {
        result.html(data);
      });
    } else {
      result.empty();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".result p", function () {
    var result = $(".result"); //important
    $(this)
      .prev()
      .children()
      .children('input[type="text"]')
      .val($(this).text());
    result.empty();
  });
});
```

I think adding this line of code should solve your problem.

Comment: not working , i want the result return from sql as the input value by click on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code that takes the value from result and place it in input.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".result", function(){
        $('#input').val($('.result').text());
    });
```

Comment: This will combine all the result values into one and replace the value of input , i want to get just one value that i click on it

Comment: If you have multiple result values. Can you share the sample of result values.